# Разделение блоков html

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой же background блока, именно синяя часть  (без кода), мне разделить блоки или это 2 фигуры или ксс свойство ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через два `<div>` можно ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать background косой в css?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253439/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-background-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-css)